# How can I schedule tasks?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, silent-mode, airplane-mode, automation

I've found an application called Silent Time, which allows me to schedule when my phone needs to go into silent mode, and when it needs to come out of it. It's a start, but I'm looking for something a bit more extended.
This is what I'd like;

### Monday, tuesday, thursday

**06:45**

- Airplane mode **OFF**
- Silent mode **OFF**
- Data traffic (3G) **ON**

**08:20**

- Silent mode **ON**

**11:55**

- Silent mode **OFF**

**12:45**

- Silent mode **ON**

**16:15**

- Silent mode **OFF**

**17:00**

- Wifi **ON**
- Data traffic **OFF**

**22:00**

- Wifi **OFF**
- Airplane mode **ON**
- Silent mode **ON**

### Wednesday

**06:45**

- Airplane mode **OFF**
- Silent mode **OFF**
- Data traffic (3G) **ON**

**08:20**

- Silent mode **ON**

**11:55**

- Silent mode **OFF**

**12:45**

- Wifi **ON**
- Data traffic **OFF**

**22:00**

- Wifi **OFF**
- Airplane mode **ON**
- Silent mode **ON**

### Friday

**06:45**

- Airplane mode **OFF**
- Silent mode **OFF**
- Data traffic (3G) **ON**

**08:20**

- Silent mode **ON**

**11:55**

- Silent mode **OFF**

**12:45**

- Silent mode **ON**

**16:15**

- Silent mode **OFF**

**17:00**

- Wifi **ON**
- Data traffic **OFF**

**22:00**

- Wifi **OFF**
- Silent mode **ON**

**23:45**

- Airplane mode **ON**

### Saturday

**09:30**

- Airplane mode **OFF**
- Silent mode **OFF**
- Wifi **ON**

**23:45**

- Airplane mode **ON**
- Silent mode **ON**

### Sunday

**09:30**

- Airplane mode **OFF**
- Silent mode **OFF**
- Wifi **ON**

**22:00**

- Airplane mode **ON**
- Silent mode **ON**

---

When I say **OFF** or **ON** it actually needs to do that, and not just switch it, so that I can switch manually without disturbing the schedule.

I need to be able to pause the schedule at any time. Being able to add exceptions (days on which to interupt the schedule) in advance would be nice, but is not required.

Is there any app or hidden feature for Android which would allow me to do this?

Comment: Look at [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Preferably a free app, of course. Also, this doesn't look like it even has anything like a sheduler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phone Schedule](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antonc.phone_schedule)

```
Switch network, modes, volume, WiFi, BT, Ringtone, Brightness, More on schedule!
All-in-one scheduler for your phone:
!NEW: Mobile Data On/Off - a feature everyone's been waiting for! (*read more below*)
!NEW: Reminder.
- Brightness! (Auto, Full, Custom, Dim Screen)
- Launch an app. (launch your internet radio to make music alarm)
- Silent mode, vibration mode, volumes(ringer, media, alarm)
- Bluetooth and WiFi ON and OFF
- Airplane Mode
- Change Ringtone and notification tone, Silent Ringtone
And more!
Create a task once and it will execute automatically. Configure time and days of week when you want it to repeat. Morning, daytime, night, weekdays, weekends, you name it! Save battery by switching off unused functions when you don't need them.
***About Mobile Data***
Mobile data is available on all supported Android versions. I have tested it on Nexus One and Samsung Galaxy Nexus. However it may not work on some phone models, i.e. on HTC EVO 4G Mobile Data Off works, but On - doesn't.
I'm very sorry if this function doesn't work on your device, very often manufacturers block this and there's nothing i can do about it :(
Phone Schedule is a tool that allows you to create a list of tasks, which you want to automatically run at specific times. For example, you might want to switch your phone to silent mode when you go to bed, so you add a task, set time to 10pm, select desired days of week(say, Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday) and select action "Set silent mode". That's it! Your phone will automatically switch to silent mode at 10pm on every Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday.
Here's an example: 
- Switch ringer off at night and switch it back on in the morning. 
- Wake up to your favorite music by launching your internet radio app.
- Make your screen brighter during day time and keep it darker in the evening to save battery.
- Switch WiFi on when you get home and switch it off when you're off to work.
- Automatically turn off mobile data when you go to bed to save battery and turn it back on when you wake up
Phone Schedule is highly configurable, supports multiple tasks at one time, lets you specify days of week when you want specific tasks to run. If you want every task to trigger a notification in your phone's notification bar, you can easily enable notifications on the Settings page. Disabling notifications is just as easy ;) "Pause Tasks" function, use it when you have unexpected business meeting, so scheduled tasks won't execute during a timeout which you set.
Phone Schedule runs in background, so once you setup your tasks, you won't need to reschedule them manually, everything is done automatically.
List of supported actions:
- Silent mode
- Vibration mode
- Normal mode
- Switch WiFi On
- Switch WiFi Off
- Switch Bluetooth On
- Switch Bluetooth Off
- Airplane Mode On
- Airplane Mode Off
- Change Ringer volume
- Change Media volume
- Change Alarm volume
- Change Notification volume
- Change Ringtone
- Silent Ringtone 
- Change Notification Tone
- Silent Notification Tone
- Brightness - Auto
- Brightness - Full
- Brightness - Cutsom
- Dim Screen
- Launch an app
- Mobile Data On (May not work on some devices)
- Mobile Data Off (May not work on some devices)
- Reminder
The list of actions is continuously growing, stay tuned for updates!
About permissions:
* Access network state, Change network state - To enable/disable mobile data 
* Full internet access - for crash reports, this greatly helps to debug the app and prevent crashes
* Change your audio settings - to set silent/vibration/normal modes and change volumes
* Automatically start an boot - to start working on your tasks automatically on boot after you reboot your phone
* create Bluetooth connections, Bluetooth administration, change WiFi state - to switch WiFi and Bluetooth On and Off(No data transmission!)
* Modify global system settings - To enable/disable Airplane mode
* Prevent phone from sleeping - to execute your tasks when your phone is sleeping
```

Answer (score 9):

With [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) you are able to achieve this. The *Tasks* can be defined as e.g. *Wifi on* and there are different trigers for those Tasks. Amoung many others, *time* can be a trigger.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) as you've wished for a free app. Further more this is a location based profile. This can not only do what you have said but also do what you want based on your location.

Comment: Looks good, let's give it a try.

Comment: This looks quite complicated. Can it also work with time, or only location?

Comment: Can work with any location as well.